# get value from one observable in another

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have this `function1()` which calls `function2()` which returns an Observable.

**function1**

```
function1(url: string):Observable<boolean> {

         return this.function2().map(res=>{
              if (this.data== true) 
              {
                   return true; 
            }
            else{
                this.router.navigate(['/error-user']);
                return false;
            }
            });
```

And `function2()` calls yet another function `function3()`.

**function2**

```
function2(){
    debugger;
    return this.service.getSettings()
        .do(

                  response => {

                      //some data

                      this.function3(); 
                      //this.data from function3() should be accesible here                                                       
                  }); 

  }
```

`function3()` subscribes to a service call.

**function3**

```
function3(){

             this.service.getUserInfo ()
                            .subscribe(
                                response => {                         
                                    //some data
                                  this.data=true; 
                                })

            }
```

Now what I want is for `this.data` in `function3()` to be accesible in `function2()` because I am making use of it in `function1()` using `map` operator.

What I have tried so far is something like below:

```
function2(){
    debugger;
    return this.service.getSettings()
        .do(

                  response => {

                      //some data

                      this.function3().map(
                      ()=> console.log( this.data) ).subscribe(()=>{return this.data}); 
                      //this.data from function3() should be accesible here                                                       
                  }); 

  }

function3(){

            return this.service.getUserInfo ()
                            .do(
                                response => {                         
                                    //some data
                                  this.data=true; 
                                })

            }
```

But with something like above I am not able to get the value of `this.data` from function3() in the scope of function2(). Further `this.data` should be passed to function1() as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Observable` also for `function3()`:

```
function3():Observable<any> {
    // do stuff and get data
    return data;
  }
```

And then subscribe to it where you need to call it and access it's data:

```
    this.function3().subscribe((data) => {
      let myData = data; // for using it inside this block
      console.log(myData);
    });
```

**Update 1:**

```
function2(){
    let myData = {}; // if data an obj
    debugger;
    return this.service.getSettings()
        .do(

                  response => {

                      //some data

                      this.myData = this.function3().subscribe((data) => {
                         return data;
                      });
                      // the data from function3() is now available here                                                       
                  }); 

  }
```

**Update 2:**

Another example for better comprehension. This is how I use it:

The function:

```
   getLoginInfo(): Observable<any> {
        return this.jsonApiService.fetch('/user/login-info.json')
            .do((user) => {
                this.userInfo = user;
                this.user.next(user);
            });
    }
```

And here is where I call it to get the data:

```
    private user: any;

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.userService.getLoginInfo().subscribe(user => {
            this.user = user;
        });
    }
```

Comment: function3 is returning an observable only if you see what I tried from my side in the question.

Comment: @AakashThakur Why don't you call `getUserInfo ()` inside `function2()`?

Comment: @AakashThakur Anyway, to access `function3()` you can do it following my approach. If you need to do stuff with the data obtained in `function3()` just subscribe to it and do the stuff you need to inside the `subscribe()`...

Comment: but how do I make `this.data` available in function1

Comment: @AakashThakur Check how to access the data in my update. If you need the data that `function3()` returns just subscribe to `function3()` in the places where you need that data.

Comment: @AakashThakur I added another update with an example of how I used this. I hope it works and helps you man! I +1 your question! Good luck!

Comment: Update1. First of all `this.data` is a boolean and secondly if i try to use `this.myData` inside `.do` I get an error that `it is not defined at the class level`.